nvm not working by default on macos terminal
Nvm doesnt work after being installed on my macbook terminal. I try to add the code given by the nvm github repo to my ~/.bashrc file like so:
Martins-MacBook-Air:~ martinbarker$ nvm
-bash: nvm: command not found
Martins-MacBook-Air:~ martinbarker$ vim ~/.bashrc
Martins-MacBook-Air:~ martinbarker$ cat ~/.bashrc
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

Martins-MacBook-Air:~ martinbarker$ source ~/.bashrc
Martins-MacBook-Air:~ martinbarker$ 


And restart the terminal. But typing nvm always gives command not found, ive tried adding this exact code to profile and zshrc as well like they say, even after restarting all terminals and my computer, it always gives nvm not found when running the command.
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
If I run source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh  then it works, but how can i make nvm work and run at the start always? Thanks

Since macOS 10.15, the default shell is zsh and nvm will look for .zshrc to update, none is installed by default. Create one with touch ~/.zshrc and run the install script again.  https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

If zsh is not your shell, nvm may not be sourced automatically. If that's the case (usinf something else than zsh), you should source nvm manually.
source "${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh"

